# In PHP what is the best way to split a string with equals and commas

Tags: php, regex, string

What would be the best way to split the following string to a key value array

```
$string = 'FullName=Thomas Marquez,Address=1234 Sample Rd, Apt 21, XX 33178,Age=37,Code=123';
```

Expected Output

```
Array
    (
        [FullName] => Thomas Marquez
        [Address] => 1234 Sample Rd, Apt 21, XX 33178
        [Age] => 37
        [Code] => 123
    )
```

Comment: explode will not work here because address field contains commas as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `preg_match_all()` with this regular expression:

```
/([a-z]+)=([^=]+)(,|$)/i
```

**Details**

```
/
([a-z]+)  match any letter 1 or more times (you can change it to \w if you need numbers
=         match a literal equal sign
([^=]+)   match anything but an equal sign, 1 or more times
(,|$)     match either a comma or the end of the string
/i        case-insensitive flag
```

like this:

```
<?php
$string = "FullName=Thomas Marquez,Address=1234 Sample Rd, Apt 21, XX 33178,Age=37,Code=123";
preg_match_all("/([a-z]+)=([^=]+)(,|$)/i", $string, $m);
var_dump($m[1]); // keys
var_dump($m[2]); // values
var_dump(array_combine($m[1], $m[2])); // combined into one array as keys and values
```

- [Code demo](https://3v4l.org/bHWn7)
- [Regex test](https://regex101.com/r/ZCb7Ok/1)

Answer (score 3):

Easy to understand how explode can do it.

```
  <?php
     $string = 'FullName=Thomas Marquez,Address=1234 Sample Rd, Apt 21, XX 33178,Age=37,Code=123';

     $arr = explode(",", $string);
     $new = array();
     foreach($arr as $key=> $value){
       if (strpos($value,"=")){
          $value2 = explode("=", $value);
          $new[$value2[0]] = $value2[1];
          $prev = $value2[0];
      }else {
         $new[$prev] .= ",".$value;
      }
    }
 print_r($new);
 ?>
```

Live demo : https://eval.in/853961